# How to stack multiple layers of conv2d_transpose() of Tensorflow

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, deconvolution

I'm trying to stack 2 layers of `tf.nn.conv2d_transpose()` to up-sample a tensor. It works fine during feed forward, but I get an error during backward propagation:
`ValueError: Incompatible shapes for broadcasting: (8, 256, 256, 24) and (8, 100, 100, 24)`.

Basically, I've just set the output of the first `conv2d_transpose` as the input of the second one:

```py
convt_1 = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(...)
convt_2 = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(conv_1)
```

Using just one `conv2d_transpose`, everything works fine. The error only occurs if multiple `conv2d_transpose` are stacked together.

I'm not sure of the proper way of implementing multiple layer of `conv2d_transpose`. Any advice on how to go about this would be very much appreciated.

Here's a small code that replicates the error:

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

IMAGE_HEIGHT = 256
IMAGE_WIDTH = 256
CHANNELS = 1

batch_size = 8
num_labels = 2

in_data = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(batch_size, IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH, CHANNELS))
labels = tf.placeholder(tf.int32, shape=(batch_size, IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH, 1))

# Variables
w0 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 3, CHANNELS, 32]))
b0 = tf.Variable(tf.zeros([32]))

# Down sample
conv_0 = tf.nn.relu(tf.nn.conv2d(in_data, w0, [1, 2, 2, 1], padding='SAME') + b0)
print("Convolution 0:", conv_0)


# Up sample 1. Upscale to 100 x 100 x 24
wt1 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 3, 24, 32]))
convt_1 = tf.nn.sigmoid(
          tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(conv_0, 
                                 filter=wt1, 
                                 output_shape=[batch_size, 100, 100, 24], 
                                 strides=[1, 1, 1, 1]))
print("Deconvolution 1:", convt_1)


# Up sample 2. Upscale to 256 x 256 x 2
wt2 = tf.Variable(tf.truncated_normal([3, 3, 2, 24]))
convt_2 = tf.nn.sigmoid(
          tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(convt_1, 
                                 filter=wt2, 
                                 output_shape=[batch_size, IMAGE_HEIGHT, IMAGE_WIDTH, 2], 
                                 strides=[1, 1, 1, 1]))
print("Deconvolution 2:", convt_2)

# Loss computation
logits = tf.reshape(convt_2, [-1, num_labels])
reshaped_labels = tf.reshape(labels, [-1])
cross_entropy = tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits, reshaped_labels)
loss = tf.reduce_mean(cross_entropy)

optimizer = tf.train.GradientDescentOptimizer(0.5).minimize(loss)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess you need to change your 'stride' paramter in conv2d_transpose. `conv2d_transpos` is like `conv2d` but input and output are reversed.

For `conv2d`, the `stride` and input shape will decide the output shape. For `conv2d_transpose`, the `stride` and output shape will decide the input shape. Now your stride is [1 1 1 1], which means output and input of `conv2d_transpose` is about same (ignoring boundary effect).

For input H = W = 100, `stride = [1 2 2 1]`, the output of `conv2d_tranpose` should be 200. (reversed of `conv2d`), if you set the `padding` to SAME. In short, input, output and stride need to be compatible.

Comment: Thanks very much @wei-liu ! That solved it. I didn't realize that the output shape needs to be computed, so that when it is convolved with the kernel at the specified stride and padding, it should result to the same shape as the input.