# Incompatible shapes between op input and calculated input gradient. conv2d_transpose any idea how to solve it?

Tags: python-3.x, tensorflow

```
def deconv2d(input_, output_shape,
         k_h=5, k_w=5, d_h=2, d_w=2, stddev=0.02,
         name="deconv2d", with_w=False):
with tf.variable_scope(name):
    # filter : [height, width, output_channels, in_channels]
```

w = tf.get_variable('w', [k_h, k_w, output_shape[-1], input_.get_shape()[-1]],
initializer=tf.random_normal_initializer(stddev=stddev))

```
    try:
        deconv = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(input_, w, output_shape=output_shape,
                            strides=[1, d_h, d_w, 1])

    # Support for verisons of TensorFlow before 0.7.0
    except AttributeError:
        deconv = tf.nn.deconv2d(input_, w, output_shape=output_shape,
                            strides=[1, d_h, d_w, 1])

    biases = tf.get_variable('biases', [output_shape[-1]], initializer=tf.constant_initializer(0.0))
    deconv = tf.reshape(tf.nn.bias_add(deconv, biases), deconv.get_shape())

    if with_w:
        return deconv, w, biases
    else:
        return deconv
```

Comment: I'm using Python3.6 with TensorFlow 1.5.1 and my issue is
[Report Error]ValueError: Incompatible shapes between op input and calculated input gradient. conv2d_transpose
any idea how to solve it?

Answer (score 0):

The error has been resolved. The problem was with the strides. Someone here already reported this issue and it really helped me to solve this problem [Detail description of this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/37444951/8343298)